# How do search array values and remove them based on a condition or string?

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

1. Read the file names from the array.
2. Search the array value for the string "-dep" and if any string value contains "-dep", remove it.
3. Pass the array as as value to another array

.

```
for($d=0; $d < $files; ++$d)
{
    if(strpos($files[$d], "-dep") === true)
    {
      unset($files[$d]);
    }
}
return array($dnum, $fnum, $dirs, $files);
```

Comment: 4. and what is the question?

Comment: `$d < $files` should probably be `$d < count($files)`

Comment: and the `strpos` should check for `>= 0` as it returns the index of the first match.

Comment: Sorry,The question was in the title. I didnt know that was unacceptable.

Comment: Curious to know why the question down voted?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best method for doing so but I would do this

```
foreach($array as $key=$value)
{
    if(strstr($value, '-dep'))
        unset($array[$key]);
}
```